# Who/such/which why one rather than another

Tags: word-choice, difference, relative-pronouns

Most people would say it’s impossible and I include  the most greatly successful among us ________ probably these people

- A) such as
- B) which are
- C) who are

Which ones are correct and which ones  aren’t?

Which one of them would a native say?

Comment: Is there any context afterwards?

Comment: No just that , but does your comment mean that which can be a correct way to referring to people in that sentence

Comment: Which mostly refers to things, but I heard it being used to refer to people too. However, I avoid doing so and instead prefer to use "who". I can't answer your question since this sentence is awkward and without context I am afraid to give a wrong answer. My suspicion is that "who are" is the correct choice.

Comment: Okay I’ll edit the question to give it more context

Comment: None of the three options make any sense to me.

Comment: _Such as_ introduces one or more _examples_. _Who are_ introduces the _particular_ people you are talking about. _Which_ would not be used of people.